# The right way to assign tasks

Tags: toloka

I am a bit worried about mixing task after the upload. Can I assign tasks to performers in the order they're uploaded without mixing them?
Another point is the possibility of using API to edit tasks, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that task pages are assigned to performers in the order they're uploaded, when configuring your pool, set the key "mix_tasks_in_creation_order"
to true. In this case, the order of tasks within the page will be different. To prevent tasks from being shuffled within pages, set the value to
false in the key
"shuffle_tasks_in_task_suite"
You can only use the API to create a task, stop assigning it, or change overlap.